# unable to access data from component to html in Angular

Tags: angular, observable, fork-join

I am using Observable.forkjoin to send multiple http requests and storing the result in a variable but I am unable to access the result in html. Can any one please help.

Service.ts :

```
addedProductIdArray : string[] =[];
reqs = [];

constructor(private _http: Http){};

getAddedProducts()  {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.addedProductIdArray.length; i++){
      this.reqs.push(this._http.get("https://my-json-server.typicode.com/shopping-cart/"+this.addedProductIdArray[i])
      .map((res: any) => res.json()));
    }
    return Observable.forkJoin(this.reqs);
  }
```

Component.ts

```
products : IProduct[];

  constructor(private _cartService : CartService) {
    this._cartService.getAddedProducts().subscribe((data: IProduct[]) => {
      this.products = data;
    });
  };
```

Component.html :

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let product of products">
    <a>{{product.title}}</a>
</ng-container>
```

I am getting product.title as empty in my html. Please help

Comment: did you log `this.products` in component? Do you see the data in it?

Comment: yes, it returns the desired array

Comment: @AnshumanJaiswal you can see the output here  - https://08b11a0437.stackblitz.io/products

Please add one or two products to the cart, then go to the cart page from the primary navigation and see the console.log.

You can see that the static data is displayed but not the "products" data

Comment: @AnshumanJaiswal I am getting the same output even after removing the map

Comment: @AnshumanJaiswal you can see the code here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/08b11a0437?file=app%2Fcart%2Fcart.service.ts

Comment: Okay, I'm checking stackblitz

Comment: I have updated the answer, it's working in stackblitz.

Comment: Thanlk you @AnshumanJaiswal :)

Comment: @AnUser there is nothing wrong with your code only there should be a change in html please check the answer I provided

Comment: @AnUser don't use foreach which will reduce the performance of your website

Comment: @AnUser great :)

Comment: @SuvethanNantha yes this helped and is perfect. Thank you :)

Comment: @AnUser in both ways (either on component or on template) there would be iteration on array. If you are managing data preparation in your code it will give you freedom to modify it if response type is being changed in future. Preferably UI must be simple and clean keeping future in mind

Comment: @AnshumanJaiswal yes you are right. It is always better to manipulate in code instead of in the view. suventhan nantha says foreach will reduce the performance. So is there any other alternate to foreach. Also, why am I getting the error "Property 'forEach' does not exist on type '{}'." in my visual studio code though am getting the output correctly? Please help me understand

Comment: @AnUser if you want to make sure the things I told about forEach, check this article.
https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/stop-array-foreach-and-start-using-filter-map-some-reduce-functions-298b4dabfa09

Comment: @AnUser read the bottom of the article you will find the paragraph regarding the performance.

Comment: @AnUser check the article https://coderwall.com/p/kvzbpa/don-t-use-array-foreach-use-for-instead

Comment: @AnUser if you want to check the performance of the foreach loop online check this https://jsperf.com/fast-array-foreach

Comment: @AnUser updated the answer.

Comment: @AnUser you can check https://codeburst.io/javascript-map-vs-foreach-f38111822c0f

Comment: Thanks @AnshumanJaiswal I prefer using the map option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While checking response in your shared URL I found it's not parsed correctly as you are using `map`

Current response is something like:

```
headers:Headers {_headers: Map(4), _normalizedNames: Map(4)}
ok:true
status:200
statusText:"OK"
type:2
url:"https://my-json-server.typicode.com/AnifaMd/shopping-cart/ec1040"
_body:"[↵  {↵    "title": "Common Projects Bball High ",↵    "id": "ec1040",↵    "color": "White",↵    "price": 540,↵    "availability": "Available"↵  }↵]"
```

while it should be:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Common Projects Bball High ",
        "id": "ec1040",
        "color": "White",
        "price": 540,
        "availability": "Available"
    }
]
```

response is array of array so you have to modify it in following way:

```
this._cartService.getAddedProducts().subscribe((data) => {
  this.products = data.map(item => item[0]);
});
```

This will work.

Comment: I am getting the same output even after removing the map

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the function in service.ts and component.ts.
You are getting the response as following.

```
[
    [{
        "title": "Common Projects Bball High ",
        "id": "ec1040",
        "color": "White",
        "price": 540,
        "availability": "Available"
    }],
    [{
        "title": "Maison Margiela Future Sneakers",
        "id": "ec1041",
        "color": "White",
        "price": 870,
        "availability": "Out of stock"
    }],
    [{
        "title": "Our Legacy Brushed Scarf",
        "id": "ec1042",
        "color": "Brown",
        "price": 349,
        "availability": "Available"
    }]
]
```

Therefore you have to change the component.html a little bit as shown below.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let product of products">
    <ng-container>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4" *ngFor="let item of product">
          <div class="card h-100">
              <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">
                      <a>{{item.title}}</a>
                  </h4>
                  <h5>{{item.price | currency:'INR'}}</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet numquam aspernatur!</p>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                  {{item.availability }}
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

I hope this will resolve your issue. If you still have issues let me know.